# Memory issues when multyplying large arryas in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm calculating weighted-average distance between multidimensional points for a large number of observations. Let's say n=2000 observations and the dimension (number of features) of each point is d=5000. The actual code is

```
# A - the weights matrix (each row corresponds to a feature, each column corresponds to an observation)
# D - distance matrix between featires (all vs all)
AA = A[:, np.newaxis] * A[np.newaxis, :]
R = AA * D[:, :, np.newaxis]
S = R.sum(axis=(0, 1))
```

The resulting array S is, therefore, a list of n float (size in bytes: s=8) numbers.
However, during the computation we need to allocate memory for AA which is n * d^2 *s = enormous amount...

I don't want to use cycles, because this procedure is running multiple times (~400), so any Python code would increase the execution time drasticly.

Any ideas?

Comment: increase space or increase time, you'll have to compromise. Perhaps try calculating the distances in chunks?

Comment: Maybe give a look at [dask](https://dask.org/)

Comment: This problem can be easily expressed in Einstein notation `S=np.einsum("jk,ji,ki->i",D,A,A,optimize='optimal')`. Numpy has a very good package to optimize this expressions. Using `numpy.einsum_path` you can look at the calculation steps. If this isn't obvious it would be good to start the optimization with a simple loop implementation, where further optimization steps are easier to see than in numpy vectorized code.